# PowerApps Filter gallery based on input text lookup from relational sharpoint list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

here I'm working on PowerApps I have 2 SharePoint lists one is challan list and one is challan details and I combine both in one gallery using the lookup function Eg:
`LookUp('Challan List',ID=ThisItem.CListID,Title)`
so for that I user multi filtering functionality, it used perfectly with combo box with pending challan and product name but now I want to search by challan list where i can search record by title and customer name my gallery item look like this for filtering.
**eg:**

```
    If(
  //this is for all and all
        ComboBox2.Selected.Result = "All" And DisplayDD.Selected.Value = "All",
        'Challan Details',
    //this is for all product and selected challan status
        ComboBox2.Selected.Result = "All" And DisplayDD.Selected.Value <> "All",
        Filter(
           'Challan Details',
            DisplayDD.SelectedText.Value = "Pending" in Text(IsBlank(Remarks))
        ),
    //this is for selected product and all challan status
        ComboBox2.Selected.Result <> "All" And DisplayDD.Selected.Value = "All",
        Filter(
            'Challan Details',
            Title = ComboBox2.Selected.Result
        ),
    //this is for selected product and selected challan status
        ComboBox2.Selected.Result <> "All" And DisplayDD.Selected.Value <> "All",
        Filter(
            'Challan Details',
            Title = ComboBox2.Selected.Result & DisplayDD.SelectedText.Value = "Pending" in Text(IsBlank(Remarks))
    //this for searchbox 
        )),
    "Created",
    Descending
)
```

so could you please tell me how to implement a filter gallery based on the search box using this code or another?[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Filter(
  MySource,
  StartsWith(
    CustomerColumn,
    Textfield.Value
  ) or
  StartsWith(
    Challan,
    TextField2.Value
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i have a relational SharePoint list and I want to search from the relational list here you give me the solution that was already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution but i have a relational SharePoint list and I want to search from the relational list here you give me the solution that was already implemented.

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Filter(
            'Challan Details',
            IsBlank(ComboBox2.SelectedItems) || IsEmpty(ComboBox2.SelectedItems) || Title in ComboBox2.SelectedItems.Title
        ),
        SearchChallan.Text in LookUp(
            'Challan List',
            ID = CListID,
            Title & CustomerName
        ),
        DisplayDD.SelectedText.Value = "Pending" in Text(IsBlank(Remarks)),
        DisplayDD.SelectedText.Value = "Completed" in Text(!IsBlank(Remarks))
    ),
    "Created",
    Descending
)
```

this is my previous code for multiple filters it works perfectly but it takes too much time to execute and gives me delegation error.

Comment: so could you please tell me how to implement a filter gallery based on the search box.
where i can search record by title and customer name.

That is exactly what was answered.
You want to look up the values in your customer table/column/choice and use that to filter?

Comment: but title and customer name is relational list you see in my above code where i can lookup the column ,

Comment: So? Filter with your list values. That’s the answer and explained already. I don’t think your question is clear enough